# asp:localize not working to translate

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, localization

I have the following somewhere in a page:

```
<asp:Localize ID="locChangePasswordPrompt" runat="server" 
     Text="Change Your Password" meta:resourcekey="locChangePasswordPrompt" />
```

I am localizing using sql server database and I have stored the FRENCH corresponding values in the db.

Do if u do a query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ResourceType]
      ,[CultureCode]
      ,[ResourceKey]
      ,[ResourceValue]
      ,[Preserve]
  FROM [CLeX].[dbo].[StringResource]
  where resourcekey like 'locChangePasswordPrompt%'
```

You get the values:

```
ResourceType                CultureCode  ResourceKey                   ResourceValue                Preserve
common/UserPreferences.aspx en           locChangePasswordPrompt                                    1
common/UserPreferences.aspx en           locChangePasswordPrompt.Text   Change Your Passwordss      1
common/UserPreferences.aspx en-US        locChangePasswordPrompt                                    1
common/UserPreferences.aspx en-US        locChangePasswordPrompt.Text   Change Your Passwordss      1
common/UserPreferences.aspx fr           locChangePasswordPrompt                                    1
common/UserPreferences.aspx fr           locChangePasswordPrompt.Text   Changez votre mot de passe  1
```

However, I am still not able to get the FRENCH values at all. In fact, not even the English values are being pulled from the DB. Localize simply pulls the text from its text attribute.
What could possibly be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your DB Resource Provider?